Local array variables in Bash 3.0
Intro
In Bash I can instantiate an empty array a using a=(). I can then append elements using e.g. a[${#a[@]}]="new element" where ${#a[@]} gives the number of elements in a. In a Bash function:
fun() {
    local a=()
    echo "size: ${#a[@]}"
    echo "content: >${a[@]}<"
}
fun  # run the function

In modern Bash versions, this prints
size: 0
content: ><  # empty

Problem
For Bash 3.0, though, I get
size: 1
content: >()<

It seems as though a is not really an array but rather a string with the value ().
I can get the usual behavior if I remove the local keyword. This suggests that mixing local and array initialization () is not supported in Bash 3.0.
Is this expected?
I am writing a large Bash script and seek to be compatible with all Bash versions down to 3.0. I can think of two solutions, neither of which are nice:

Only use global array variables.
Ignore the first element of a if this is equal to (), once a has been fully populated with elements. This (somewhat surprisingly) works because even when a is the string (), array appends a[${#a[@]}]="new element" still works, effectively converting a to an array the original string value () as the first element.

Any better ideas?
Test
To test things out with Bash 3.0, I use Docker:
docker run --rm bash:3.0 bash -c 'fun() { local a=(); echo "size: ${#a[@]}"; echo "content: >${a[@]}<"; }; fun'

The problem goes away already wih bash:3.1.

Likely a bug. You can try local a; a=() instead of local a=().

What environment are you targeting that bash 3.0 is likely to be used? You're making Apple look progressive...

@chepner Badly maintained clusters ...

Generally, a=() doesn't define a at all; it just sets the array attribute, as if you used declare -a a. (Check the exit status of a=() && [[ -v a ]].)

@RenaudPacalet that actually works!

Assignment of an "empty" array to a name doesn't actually define a variable at all; it just sets the array attribute of the name. Some options:

declare -a a
local a; a=()
local -a a

What you are seeing appears to be a bug in Bash 3.0's implementation of local (subsequently fixed in Bash 3.1) that doesn't properly recognize array assignments.
